# Trying to limit text in android textview

Tags: android, textview

Okay so say I have a fixed width TextView and the text inside it is way longer.

How can I replace the overflowed text to "..."

Example: "Hello my name is John" changed to "Hello my name is..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the [`android:ellipsize` property](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize) on the `TextView` as required (probably to 'end').

Answer (score 2):

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:ellipsize="end" />
```